# Can we combine logback-spring.xml and logback-access.xml as a single file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback, logstash-logback-encoder

Is there any way to combine logback-spring.xml and logback-access.xml as a single file in a spring-boot application?

Answer (score 0):

No. Logback does not support that (as of v1.2.10)